# Parse and Select mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using mongodb and facing a problem
That I want to select host from URL that are stored in mongodb document (JSON).

How can I do that in real time ?

What I am currently doing is first updating mongodb record with the host for each record and then after that I do group by on host.

For eg. suppose I have url like http://example.com/a/b/c then I update each record with the domain that means example.com(say as host ) then I select host for my group by operation.

So basically I want to select the host but without updating each record with host.

Is that possible?How?

Thanks.

Dont know if someone got this or not.
So clear example is (as I think),
Before update i have this

1.
`{
  "url": "http://www.example.com/a/b/c"
}`

After update I make this as

2.
`{
  "url": "http://www.example.com/a/b/c",
  "host":"www.example.com" 
}`

So I want to select host without updating document, in my group by query.

-----Another Explaination.
I have a mongo document as above with just url (pointed as 1 above)
So How can I do a group by query on url's host no the url itself.

```
       query = new BasicDBObject();            

        key = new BasicDBObject();
        key.put("url", true);

        DBCursor cursor = table.find(query,key);

        while(cursor.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(cursor.next()); //will print whole url
        }

        System.out.println("============Printing only host(domain) from url");

        key = new BasicDBObject();
        key.put("url", true);

        cursor = table.find(query,key);

        while(cursor.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(new URL(cursor.next().get("url").toString()).getHost());        //will print only host www.example.com
        }
```

`

The above code will print the url first and then only host using Cursor.

But I want to group by on host(domain of the url) by extracting it somehow.

So that's why what i m doing currently, I first do group by on url to get unique url then using URL class of JAVA NET package I get host (using `.getHost()` method ) for each unique url of my JSON document and update it with the host as I have shown in point (2) above.

Now I can easily do group by on host.

But but I dont want to update the mongo document first,
I just want to directly do group by on host (that means selecting url but in real time parsing host from it) so i can reduce one step of updating each document with host.

Is that possible?

Something what we can do in mysql I think like this `select somefunction_gethost(url) from table`

I think now i cant make it more clear.

Please check this and give a solution if it has a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you may need to show a somewhat clearer example, the current description makes my head spin :)

Comment: I mean that I have a URL and I want to select host (or say Extract) from it. Is that possible ?
BasicDBObject key = new BasicDBObject ();
key.put("url",true); //this will give me the url
But what about something like this 
key.put(new URL("url").getHost(),true);// dont know this work or not

So if I have http://example.com/a/b/c so this 
key.put("url",true); will produce http://example.com/a/b/c

but i want only host of url example.com. How can i get that?

Comment: Have you checked any URL library?

Comment: I m using java.net.URL package in my code, but what is URL library?
is it for mongodb java driver?

Comment: can you make it more clear do you want two fields(url and host) in your document or just one field with data "www.example.com"